# Reference Terraform variable in shell script using templatefile function

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+, terraform-template-file

I have a shell script to download a http link using wget:

```
wget -qO - "${mojang_server_url}"
```

I want to enter this link in a tfvars file, and then reference this in the shell script using Terraform.

[I found a good solution here using template_file data source (it works)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48993080/17652461)

```
data "template_file" "setup_script" {
 template = file("setup.sh")
 vars = {
  mojang_server_url = "${var.mojang_server_url}"
 }
}
```

However, the [official Terraform documentation for template_file](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/template/latest/docs/data-sources/file) tells me I should be using the templatefile function instead?

I can't seem to figure out the syntax for this function, here's what I've got:

```
templatefile("setup.sh",{"mojang_server_url"="${var.mojang_server_url}")
```

it highlights templatefile, saying:

> Argument or block definition required: An argument or block definition
> is required here. To set an argument, use the equals sign "=" to
> introduce the argument value.

Is there a way to make it so this can reference the tfvars variable ina shell script?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just simply have to provide a map as an input for the second argument:

```
data "template_file" "setup_script" {
  template = templatefile("setup.sh",
    {
      mojang_server_url = var.mojang_server_url
    }
  )
}
```

Comment: thank you! I was assuming you had to replace template_file resource with templatefile function but you used them together